Ошибка при проверки подписки на телеграм канал aiogram
Гуглил, спрашивал у ИИ, безуспешно, юзер нейм группы - @over_crypton, версия 3.x, код:
CHANNEL_ID = '@over_crypton'


@router.callback_query(F.data == 'check_verif')
async def check_subs(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = call.from_user.id
    try:
        user = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, user_id=user_id)
        if user.status in ['member', 'administrator', 'creator']:
            await call.message.answer("Вы подписаны на канал")
        else:
            await call.message.answer("Вы не подписаны на канал")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await call.message.answer("Произошла ошибка при проверке подписки")

В ошибке пишет что "Сервера телеграм сказали - плохой запрос" ошибка в строчке user = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, user_id=user_id), кто знает помогите!

Решение очень простое, надо было просто добавить бота в канал.
